# Code in if statement suddenly leaves

Tags: java, sql, servlets, if-statement

I have  an if statement I have checked with breakpoints that my program is entering the if statement and it is. I can follow through my statement till I get to the prepare statement line then my if statement appears to break out for no reason and not executing any code under my prepare statement. I have searched for my issue and can't get any solutions.

```
 if(entry != null && subNum.equals(1) && rs.getRow() == 1)
 {
         String blogID = rs.getString(1);
         String timeStamp = rs.getString(2);
         java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
         String tStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString();
         query = "INSERT INTO blog_entries VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
         ps.setString(1, entry);
         out.print(entry);
         ps.setString(2, timeStamp);
         out.print(timeStamp);
         ps.setString(3, tStamp);
         out.print(tStamp);
         ps.setString(4, entry);
         out.print(entry);
         ps.setString(5, blogID);
         out.print(blogID);
         ps.executeUpdate();
         out.println("Submit Successful");
 }
```

The out.prints are there just for debugging purposes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're getting an exception. Log the exception trace and add it to the  question.

Comment: Maybe you are getting an exception on the prepare? Does `blog_entries` have exactly 5 columns? Best practice is to specify the names of the columns, i.e. `INSERT INTO blog_entries (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Thanks @KlasLindbäck it appears I was trying to insert into the wrong database table. Thanks also to everyone who answered you all helped me work out what was wrong.

Comment: Just so it's said, if you hadn't been ignoring exceptions somewhere, this mysterious "break" would have been instantly obvious, to the point of even *showing up as a database error on line such-and-such*.  *This* is why we don't swallow exceptions, people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `con` is not initiated if its breaking on the 1st use of it, can u confirm it is not null at the line its used? if yes catch and post the exception like:

```
 if(entry != null && subNum.equals(1) && rs.getRow() == 1)
 {
         String blogID = rs.getString(1);
         String timeStamp = rs.getString(2);
         java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
         String tStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString();
         query = "INSERT INTO blog_entries VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         try{
                if (con != null)
                {
                     ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                     ps.setString(1, entry);
                     out.print(entry);
                     ps.setString(2, timeStamp);
                     out.print(timeStamp);
                     ps.setString(3, tStamp);
                     out.print(tStamp);
                     ps.setString(4, entry);
                     out.print(entry);
                     ps.setString(5, blogID);
                     out.print(blogID);
                     ps.executeUpdate();
                } else { 
                     // print error and break }                    
            }
      catch (Exception e){
         //print error message
     }
         out.println("Submit Successful");
 }
```

Comment: Maybe print something if `con == null`. Now it will print `Submit Successful`. The successful printing should probably be after last statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're "randomly" breaking out of a block, it probably means you're throwing an exception.  If it's failing when you try to create the PreparedStatement, then it's likely that either the SQL is invalid or you can't establish a connection.

Aws @Marko points out, however, your SQL statement does look valid.  So I would check the `con` object.  However, you should be able to check the exception's stack trace for more useful information instead of just guesswork.

Comment: The syntax looks perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

prepareStatement throws a SQLException, so surround that with try/catch to see if that's your problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)